# Take string and compare to multiple enum types all at once

Tags: java, enums

I really need help here.

If I have my separate class, lets call it FileType.java, and it looks like this:

```
 public enum FileType
 {
     JPG,GIF,PNG,BMP,OTHER
 }
```

and then I grab a string from the user, call it inputString, how can I compare "inputString" to every single enum value, with the most **minimal** amount of code?

EDIT: Here is what I have tried:

```
    System.out.print("Please enter your photo's file type. It must be: JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP, or OTHER");
    typeInput = kb.nextLine();

    boolean inputMatches = false;

    while(inputMatches == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid input. Please enter your photo's file type. It must be: JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP, or OTHER");

        if(typeInput.equalsIgnoreCase(FileType.values()))
        {
            inputMatches = true;
        }
    }
```

Ps. I am well aware that I can just set individual variables to equal the same strings as the enum values. I;m also aware that I could use `.valueOf()` for every single value.

Comment: Show us, what you have tried.

Comment: alright here's what I've tried, but it's flawed at the moment.

Comment: why don't you use `FileType.valueOf(userInput)`? If it throws `IllegalArgumentException` the input is invalid otherwise it gives you the enum value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert input to enum instead

```
System.out.print("Please enter your photo's file type. It must be: JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP, or OTHER");
boolean typeInput = kb.nextLine();

inputMatches = true;
try{
    FileType fileType = FileType.valueOf(inputString.toUpperCase().trim());
}catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    inputMatches = false;
}
```

Comment: @Chisx: Just to remove spaces

Comment: I'm sorry but this is confusing me. Is this the conditional? Like to put in the loop? I would use this, but this is advanced for what we're doing. We have not learned exceptions yet

Comment: I've never seen "try" and "catch", but this is a great answer regardless @Karna

Comment: Hey what is the 'e' after the IllegalArgumentException?? @Karna

Comment: @Chisx [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: @Chisx: Please read some tutorials before you jump and start coding.

Comment: Thank you Karna, I agree completely, but we have not covered exceptions in my college's sophomore level "Intro II" course. That is why I was not even thinking about using an exception. @Karna